# stop called in state 1

Tags: android, media-player

I could not resolve this media player error which says "stop called in state 1".my media player actually delays for few seconds before moving on to the next music.can anyone help me.

Answer (score 3):

this might help u...

```
package com.commonsware.android.audio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AudioDemo extends Activity
  implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

  private ImageButton play;
  private ImageButton pause;
  private ImageButton stop;
  private MediaPlayer mp;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    play=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
    pause=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pause);
    stop=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.stop);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
        play();
      }
    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
        pause();
      }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
        stop();
      }
    });

    setup();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (stop.isEnabled()) {
      stop();
    }
  }

  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    stop();
  }

  private void play() {
    mp.start();

    play.setEnabled(false);
    pause.setEnabled(true);
    stop.setEnabled(true);
  }

  private void stop() {
    mp.stop();
    pause.setEnabled(false);
    stop.setEnabled(false);

    try {
      mp.prepare();
      mp.seekTo(0);
      play.setEnabled(true);
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
      goBlooey(t);
    }
  }

  private void pause() {
    mp.pause();

    play.setEnabled(true);
    pause.setEnabled(false);
    stop.setEnabled(true);
  }

  private void loadClip() {
    try {
      mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.clip);
      mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
      goBlooey(t);
    }
  }

  private void setup() {
    loadClip();
    play.setEnabled(true);
    pause.setEnabled(false);
    stop.setEnabled(false);
  }

  private void goBlooey(Throwable t) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder
      .setTitle("Exception!")
      .setMessage(t.toString())
      .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
      .show();
  }
}
```